# Undeclared identifier. "test function" is not (or not yet) visible at this point

Tags: solidity, smart-contract-wallets

```
function mint(uint256 quantity) external payable callerIsUser {
        // `_mint`'s second argument now takes in a `quantity`, not a `tokenId`.
        if(whiteListSale)
        {
            whitelistMint(quantity);  <--(Undeclared identifier. "whitelistMint" is not (or not yet) visible at this point.)
        }
        else if(publicSale)
        {
            publicMint(quantity);  <--(Undeclared identifier. "publicMint" is not (or not yet) visible at this point.)
        }
        else
        {
            //Sold Out
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you have whitelistMint() or publicMint() function in your contract? If yes, are they external? If yes, change them to public. That will work.

Comment: thx...............